# RegExp - Grabbing only the important information from a string

Tags: regex, string

I tried the following at http://gskinner.com/RegExr, there it worked perfectly.
Now I want to get the `/(?&lt;=>\r\s{23})(.*)/gi` pattern realized in PHP. The > character don't perform well, also not with backslashes...

I want to get the `&nbsp;&nbsp;2011&nbsp;Oct&nbsp;3, Mon`, `Unity Day` and `&nbsp;` in the mid of every `<FONT></FONT>`.

Searching string:

```
      `<TR>
         <TD ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT=17 
              WIDTH=175  BGCOLOR=lightblue>
               <FONT COLOR=red SIZE=2>
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;2011&nbsp;Oct&nbsp;3, Mon
               </FONT>
         </TD>
         <TD ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT=17 
              WIDTH=150 BGCOLOR=lightblue>

         <FONT COLOR=black SIZE=2>
                   Unity Day
               </FONT>
         </TD>
         <TD ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT=17 
              WIDTH=275 BGCOLOR=lightblue>
         <FONT COLOR=black SIZE=2>
                   &nbsp;
               </FONT>
         </TD>

     </TR>`
```

Any ideas, other solutions, etc.?

Greetings
Eminenz

Answer (score 1):

This will be echoed many times on stack overflow - don't use regex to parse XML/HTML.

Check out the DOM parser: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_dom.asp

Comment: Thank you!

I will have a look on that.